# Adaptive Layout with Trait Collection in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to layout a UIView on screen to be at the top at an aspect ratio of 16:9 when device is in portrait mode, and to be full screen when device is in landscape mode (like a video player screen). I decided to use size classes. Here is how i was able to achieve it but i'm not satisfied with the the implementation and there are some bugs. Here is my code:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        localPlayerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    } 
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        localPlayerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    }

    if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
        localPlayerView.removeFromSuperview()

        view.addSubview(localPlayerView)

        let height = view.frame.width * 9 / 16
        localPlayerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: height)
        collectionView.anchor(top: localPlayerView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        localPlayerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I had to remove the localPlayerView from superview and add it back to get the desired result because, it was still constraining to full superview width when i switch back to portrait. 
How can I improve this code to achieve the same result?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah, the answer provided works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you give the `localPlayerView` new constraints defining its size and position, you have to remove/deactivate the old constraints. In your code it seems that you are always just adding new constraints, which will result in unsatisfiable constraints and then problems in layout - morever, if you remove the player from the superview and then add it again, that will remove those constraints - that only confirms my hypothesis. You have to be careful to always have non-conflicting constraints.

Just a broad guidelines as how you can do it. Define two properties in the `viewController`:

```
var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
```

Then, once the view is loaded (e.g., in `viewDidLoad`) populate them accordingly:

```
portraitConstraints = [ 
    // here create all the constraints that are needed to properly define position and size of the player when in portrait
]
landscapeConstraints = [ 
    // all the constraints for landscape
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstraints) // activate these as default
```

Then in the `traitCollectionDidChange` detect if you are in landscape or in portrait (I omit this code, you can find SO questions about that), and just activate the proper constraints (and deactivate old ones):

```
let inLandscape = // code to detect current orientation
if inLandscape {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(portraitConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscapeConstraints)
} else {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscapeConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstraints)
}
```